# Noetherian ring that isn't euclidean?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Can anyone give me an example of one? I know it's equivalent to finding a noetherian that isn't PID, but I'm not sure!

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Comment: @Levent Can you explain why please?

Comment: i dont think the phrase "i know it's equivalent to finding a noetherian that isnt a pid" is correct (see the answer below). maybe in this way you could get the question open again. for instance you could ask: "a example of noetherian ring that is a pid and not euclidean" (check that this is not already asked also)

Answer (score -1):

The ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ is a principal ideal domain that is not Euclidean.

Comment: I think some people found this answer more sophisticated than necessary.

Comment: @user26857, perhaps, but this example makes a strong point: A ring may be *very* Noetherian (a PID!) but not Euclidean.